# File Upload to Raspberry Pi server not working - Python/Flask

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, raspberry-pi

I am developing a Flask 'utility' application with a built in Flask/HTML file manager that does file uploading from clients that access the application through Apache Webserver running on a Raspberry Pi.

The file uploading works perfectly fine on my local Mac machine using the local PyCharm development server. When used on Raspberry Pi, everything works fine, except the File Uploading.

When I attempt to upload an image file from my machine to the Raspberry Pi, I get this screen after clicking the "Upload" button:

> Error 400: Bad Request; The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Here is my code:

**main.py (file portion, I can provide full code if needed)**

```
@app.route('/files', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def file():
    tag = request.form.get('folder')
    path = setFilePath(tag)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if "upload" in request.form:
            upload(tag)
        elif "view" in request.form:
            path = setFilePath(tag)

    files = dir_listing(path)

    if tag == None:
        tag = "Documents"

    return  render_template('upload.html', files = files, path = tag)
```

**file.py**

```
def setFilePath(folder):
    #Get the root of this python file
    root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    if folder is None:
        # If the user just loaded the page there won't be a directory, so documents is default
        folder = "Documents"

    #Add the /static/media path to the full path
    path = root + '/static/media/' + folder

    return path

def upload(tag):
    path = setFilePath(tag)
    print(path)

    #Tried these contents both with and without a for loop
    for file in request.files.getlist("files"):
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([path, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)

def dir_listing(path):
    # Show directory contents
    files = os.listdir(path)
    return files
```

**upload.html**

```
<form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('file') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload Path</label>
    <select name="folder" id="subdir">
        <option value="Documents">Documents</option>
        <option value="Music">Music</option>
        <option value="Pictures">Pictures</option>
    </select>

    <input type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
    <input type="submit" name="view" value="View">

</form>

<h3>Current Folder: {{ path }}</h3>
<ul>
    {% for file in files %}
    <li><p>{{ file }}</p></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**EDIT: Apache Configuration**

**wsgi file**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant")
from main import app as application
```

**apache2.conf file**

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Site Configuration File (in /etc/apache2/sites-available)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAdmin pi@localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/static
        <Directory /var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE: /var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.389752 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] mod_wsgi (pid=1777): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant.wsgi'., referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.419798 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420542 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 100, in wrapper, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420592 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420684 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 212, in _parse_multipart, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420729 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420818 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 523, in parse, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420859 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return self.cls(form), self.cls(files), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420947 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 384, in __init__, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.420988 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     for key, value in mapping or ():, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421073 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 521, in <genexpr>, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421115 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == 'form'), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421201 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 480, in parse_parts, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421243 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421331 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 394, in parse_lines, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421373 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     terminator = self._find_terminator(iterator), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421460 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 322, in _find_terminator, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421500 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     for line in iterator:, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421586 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 821, in make_line_iter, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421627 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     first_item = next(_iter, ''), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421712 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 781, in _make_chunk_iter, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421807 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     item = _read(buffer_size), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421894 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 1042, in read, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.421935 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return self.on_disconnect(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422117 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 1010, in on_disconnect, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422158 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     raise ClientDisconnected(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422329 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400: Bad Request, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422433 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] , referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422473 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422510 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] , referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.422594 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423610 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423655 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423745 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423786 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     response = self.handle_exception(e), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423871 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423912 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.423997 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424037 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     raise value, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424122 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424162 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424246 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424316 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424403 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424445 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424529 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424570 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     raise value, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424654 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424695 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424778 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424819 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424905 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "var/www/SwissArmyAssistant/SwissArmyAssistant/main.py", line 67, in file, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.424946 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     tag = request.form.get('folder'), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425031 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425072 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425156 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 73, in __get__, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425197 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     value = self.func(obj), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425281 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 492, in form, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425321 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     self._load_form_data(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425406 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/wrappers.py", line 185, in _load_form_data, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425447 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     RequestBase._load_form_data(self), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425532 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 361, in _load_form_data, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425598 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     mimetype, content_length, options), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425684 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 195, in parse, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425726 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     content_length, options), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425809 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 104, in wrapper, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425849 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     exhaust(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425933 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 1024, in exhaust, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.425973 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     self.read(chunk), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.426056 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 1042, in read, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.426097 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     return self.on_disconnect(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.426180 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 1010, in on_disconnect, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.426221 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966]     raise ClientDisconnected(), referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
[Thu Nov 01 09:14:04.426358 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 1777:tid 1938814000] [client 169.254.107.121:51966] werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400: Bad Request, referer: http://169.254.142.67/files
```

I have tried every suggestion on many forums on Stack Overflow, but to no avail. There is no indication in the error.log of Apache2 that anything is wrong.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could be that the apache config is the problem. Please add relevant parts of your apache config to the question.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated this with the apache files

Comment: Hmm. You use mod_wsgi, right? I expect to find a WSGIScriptAlias directive in the apache config, perhaps it is in another file? Have you configured WSGIScriptAlias somehow? If so, please post the contents of that file.

Comment: Yes, I just put the code in for the site config file. Thank you again for your continued help.

Comment: Set the flask config variable ``TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS`` to True (``app.config['TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS'] = True``) and see if this gets you a stack trace in the browser window.

Comment: You might also need to set ``DEBUG`` to ``True``: ``app.config['DEBUG'] = True``

Comment: Thank you, I checked the error.log file after implementing your suggestions, and I updated the post with the contents. Appears to be some sort of timeout?

Comment: This only occurs when uploading images over 60KB, anything under this size and the upload works perfectly.

Comment: OK then it must be some sort of request body size limitation in apache, this can be configured.

Comment: I tried making a .htaccess file, but this did not work.

Comment: Where is this limitation configured in Apache?

Comment: It could either be ``LimitRequestBody`` or ``LimitXMLRequestBody`` . The default value (2GB) for ``LimitRequestBody`` should be OK, and I guess your request is not XML so perhaps this is not the case after all.

Comment: What version of ``mod_wsgi`` is running? This looks related: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1068 and according to the discussion there, there was a bug in mod_wsgi that was fixed in version 4.5.15. So if you're running an older version of mod_wsgi you could try upgrading.

Comment: I am running the latest version. I just, sort of, solved the issue. I tried running my project on an Ubuntu Server and that worked perfectly fine. File uploads happened with no trouble at all. My Raspberry Pi was the thing giving me the issues, which does not make sense at all, but at least I made some headway.

Comment: Thank you again for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Any other version differences, perhaps? Apache version on RPi vs on the Ubuntu server?